# Matching a regex metacharacter literally

Tags: regex, awk

My understanding of Regex's in AWK is that in order to match a Regex metacharacter literally (For example: +,$,^,*,etc) You must escape them, like so:

```
awk -F '\\+' 'program here'
```

However I've noticed that you don't actually need to do this with certain metacharacters, such as the "+"

Input file:

```
this|is|a|line
this+is+a+line
this?is?a?line
this*is*a*line
this$is$a$line
this.is.a.line
```

AWK program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = "+|^"}

{print $1,$2,$3,$4 }
```

Expected output (Due to not escaping the +):

```
this|is|a|line
this+is+a+line
this?is?a?line
this*is*a*line
this$is$a$line
this.is.a.line
```

Actual output:

```
this|| is|| a|| line
his|is|a|line
this is a line
his?is?a?line
his*is*a*line
his$is$a$line
his.is.a.line
```

I don't understand how this is working. I'm giving AWK blatantly bad code by not escaping the metacharacter (to make it literal) however AWK is matching successfully anyway?

I own a copy of "The AWK programming language" so I went through the section on Regex just to make sure I'm not going mad, and it states the following:

> In a matching expression, a quoted string like "^[0-9]+$" can normally be used interchangeably with a regular expression enclosed in slashes, such as /^[0-9]+$/. There is one exception, however. If the string in quotes is to match a literal occurrence of a regular expression metacharacter, one extra backslash is needed to protect the protecting backslash itself. That is,
>
> $0  ~ /(\+|-)[0-9]+/
>
> and
>
> $0  ~ "(\\+|-)[0-9]+"
>
> are equivalent.
>
> This behavior may seem arcane, but it arises because one level of protecting backslashes is removed when a quoted string is parsed by awk. If a backslash is needed in front of a metacharacter to turn off its special meaning in a regular expression, then that backslash needs a preceding backslash to protect it in a string.

Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Comment: Never mind. I missed an important detail in the documentation [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operator-Details.html). Specifically this part: > In POSIX awk and gawk, the ‘*’, ‘+’, and ‘?’ operators stand for
> themselves when there is nothing in the regexp that precedes them. For
> example, /+/ matches a literal plus sign. However, many other versions
> of awk treat such a usage as a syntax error.

Comment: The section you quoted from "The AWK Programming Language" has nothing to do with your question. It's talking about how escapes are interpreted in dynamic regexps, not how a repetition metachar at the start of a regexp is interpreted.

Comment: The section you quoted from "Effective AWK Programming" in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297565/matching-a-regex-metacharacter-literally#comment134546565_76297565) is wrong about POSIX awk and will be fixed in a future release. The meaning of `*`, `+` or `?` at the start of a regexp is undefined in POSIX.

Comment: @Ed Morton
You're right. I just quoted it in case the behaviour I was seeing was due to the difference between /regex/ and "regex" in AWK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` is at the start of the pattern: it can't modify anything before that (i.e., allowing 1 or more of the non-existing character in front of it), thus awk interprets it as a literal `+` character, not a modifier.

From the gawk manual, on [regex operator details](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Regexp-Operator-Details.html)

> In POSIX awk and gawk, the ‘*’, ‘+’, and ‘?’ operators stand for themselves when there is nothing in the regexp that precedes them. For example, /+/ matches a literal plus sign. However, many other versions of awk treat such a usage as a syntax error.

Comment: Yep I just saw that in the manual. Doh!
Thank you for taking the time to reply. I appreciate it.

Comment: The [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_03) disagrees with that (emphasis mine): - "`*+?{`
    The <asterisk>, <plus-sign>, <question-mark>, and <left-brace> shall be special except when used in a bracket expression (see RE Bracket Expression). Any of the following uses produce undefined results: **If these characters appear first in an ERE**". So according to the POSIX spec having `+` first in a regexp (and by extension a `FS`) is undefined behavior and so any POSIX-compliant awk can do whatever they like with `FS = "+|^"`.

Comment: It looks like the OP is using `gawk`, and the gawk manual is incorrect when mentioning POSIX awk in this context.

Comment: @9769953 I tried in both AWK and GAWK. Same behavior in both.

Comment: @the_slug there is no single "awk". There's gawk, mawk1, mawk2, BSD awk, tawk, /usr/xpg6/bin/awk, nawk, one true awk, and several others. So if you test in some "awk" that's not gawk, that doesn't mean all non-gawk awk variants behave the same way even if they are all POSIX compliant. I opened a bug report for gawk (https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-05/msg00020.html) to request they clarify their statement about "POSIX awk" in the gawk manual.

Comment: @EdMorton Nice to see these kind of follow-ups on SO questions. Thanks for doing that, even if it's just a tiny thing in the manual.

Comment: FYI the gawk provider said he will eventually push a fix to the gawk documentation to correct it to match the POSIX spec and state that in POSIX awk a `*`, `+`, or `?` at the start of a regexp is undefined behavior, see https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2023-05/msg00025.html.